# Notepad++ fixing after a crash, interpreting the .dmp interpretation

Tags: notepad++, crash-recovery

My notepad++ experienced a crash after I attempted renaming a file when it was closed and restarted the program.

According to the .dmp information it was reading/writing to virtual memory without permission.

Here's some additional information to help delimit the problem

- The source of the problem is not the filename (replacing the old did
  not work)
- The problem does not occur by UAC
- I am currently working on full text files with no "strange" addiotional things going on
- I can't see a documentation reference to what version I'm using but the installer suggests 5.9.3 (the dmp file has the same version number reference)

My question would be this:

Is there a means besides reinstall to tackle this problem, for example , could I find a cache system/mechanism to help me decide what notepad++ loads (file references in particular). Im asking partially to solve the problem quickly and partially to learn a little more in how these operations are handled.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I seem to made the title....well plain wrong. If a mod/adm could fix it or tell me how I could that would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't a cache or ini file I needed it was the session.XML file in %APPDATA%

Deleting this succesfully removed the load reference to the file and everything works fine again now.